# how to fit react-native element avatar image component to the screen?

Tags: react-native

I am  a beginner to react-native,I trying to create a view containing image and buttons.

**welcomepage.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View,Image,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Card,Button,Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
export default class WelcomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Avatar
              width={450}
              containerStyle={{flex: 0.37}}
              imageProps={{resizeMode:'cover'}}
              source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')}
              onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
            />
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flex:0.5}}>
                <Button  large title='LOGIN' icon={{name: 'user-secret',type:'font-awesome'}} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
                <Button  large title='REGISTER' icon={{name: 'user-plus',type:'font-awesome'}} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
            </View> 
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WelcomePage from './components/welcomePage';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <WelcomePage />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**output **
[image]

in the above code everything working nicely, but how can I fit the image to the left,right and top position of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [Avatar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/avatar.html) in the [`react-native-elements`](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements) is an [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#docsNav) wrapped in a component, therefore you can do the following

Note that `xLarge` prop needs to be removed , since it is their specific layout prop.

You need to supply the `screenWidth`, since the component is made in such a way that, it `wraps` based on the `children elements`.

**WelcomePage.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View,Image,StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Card,Button,Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window')
export default class WelcomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Avatar
                    width={width}
                    overlayContainerStyle={{flex: 0.4}} /*Some Layout fixes*/
                    imageProps={{resizeMode: 'cover'}} /*If you want your image to scale*/
                    source={{uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoVWQ.png'}}
                    onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                />
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flex: 0.6}}>
                    <Button  title='LOGIN' />
                    <Button  title='REGISTER' />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <WelcomePage />
 </View>
```

Comment: how can i adjust the unwanted space between the image and the buttons?

Comment: Button `container` contains a default `margin` of `15`, you may try overriding it on the [container styles](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/button.html)

Comment: done by adding flex to 'containerstyle' props of avatar component

Comment: how can i set the view container of both image and button at the center of the screen?

Comment: The `parent container` of the `image` and `button` is already set in my answer using `alignItems: 'center'`, this is horizontal centering, for vertical centering use `justifyContent :center`

Comment: i am edited the question by updating welcome.js and the output image.please check it.

Comment: need to give 'margintop' to the view container?